# python: efficiently build and maintain a sortedlist of strings in decreasing order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance

I want to *efficiently* build and fill a list with strings representing file names.

File names have a well defined structure that looks like:

`'20190810-012500_foo_bar_eggs.zip'`,

where the initial number represent a date in the format %Y%m%d-%H%M%S.

I'd like the list to be built in decreasing time order.

The following works for increasing order, but I'm failing to reverse it. 
Please note that the key below works probably the same as not-specifying a key at all. I just want to show a possible way to use a key.

```
import os
import time
from blist import sortedlist

l = sortedlist([], key= lambda x: time.strptime(x[:15], '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'))

for f in os.listdir(my_dir):  # the number of files can be big
    if "_foo_" in f:   # I need to filter out some
        l.add(f)
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The most important thing for me here is efficiency. Trivial solutions could be simply sort after the list has been created, use the key as in my sample code and reverse the list in the end, do all of the above in just one list comprehension, and so on. I'm looking to minimize the number of operations and maximize efficiency.

I think (and may be wrong) that a sortedlist might be an efficient way, but if you know something better please let me know. Thank you.

PS. blist docs [here](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/).

Comment: Would a Binary Search Tree interest you?

Comment: @GeorgeBou blist implementation is based on B+Trees. Do you think binary search tree would work better? I'm interested in anything that efficiently gets the job done.

Comment: I would seriously think about Binary Search Tree for your case. It is way faster O(log(n)) and more efficient as it can dynamically add new elements without needing to resort etc. Plus you can implement it to sort items in decreasing order. You might just have to implement the insert(), delete() and search() functions yourself as well as the Node class. P.S. i am not aware of blist complexity, efficiency etc.

Answer (score 1):

#### time.mktime

Try using `time.mktime()` to convert the `struct_time` returned by `strptime()` into an float.  Add a `-` sign to reverse the sort.

```
def newest_first(s):
    return -time.mktime(time.strptime(s[:15], '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'))

l = sortedlist([], key=oldest_first)
```

Comment: Oh nice trick, thanks. +1 for now because it does what I want, let me run some tests. By the way, maybe "newest_first" is a better name, as with this actually we are getting most recent timestamps first. Also your `x` should be an `s`.. can't edit as it is less than 6 char edit.